# Unable connect to BitBucket Using SmartGit

Tags: git, bitbucket, smartgit

I trying to setup the smartgit which connect to BitBucket hosting provider.

I enter the username(email) and password as same as I login to the website but it display connect time out.

I wonder it is related to firewall issue or other things. 
Is it require to configure the git before using smart git. I'm using msysgit for window.

Thanks.

Comment: Could be a firewall or Proxy (see Preferences - Check for New Version). Can you connect from command line?

Comment: How to check from command line ? What command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using git command line to push code to bitbucket.